# PrimeNG p-multiSelect Customize label of selected Items

Tags: primeng

I'm quite new to Angular and needed help in for a requirements.

- The dropdown should have `Select All` as the option for user to
  select all items.
- The `selectedItemsLabel` need to be
  dynamically selected to have 2 or 3 selected values as per size and
  rest with `+{remaining} more` label.

[image: Requirement Screenshot]

I have so far written code like this - [Link.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-placeholder-kknspj) Any help would be appreciated.